# Plotting 4 different types of tides

Tags: python, matplotlib

I trying to plot 4 different graphs displays the four different types of tides. With varying amplitudes and phase shifts.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Define tidal constituents from Table 4.1
constituents = [
    {"symbol": "M2", "period": 12.42, "relative_amplitude": 100.0},
    {"symbol": "S2", "period": 12.00, "relative_amplitude": 46.6},
    {"symbol": "K1", "period": 23.93, "relative_amplitude": 58.4},
    {"symbol": "O1", "period": 25.82, "relative_amplitude": 41.5},
]
# Define the time series for one month (31 days, 24 hours per day)
days = 31
hours_per_day = 24
total_hours = days * hours_per_day
time = np.linspace(0, total_hours, total_hours, endpoint=False)  # Hours
# Initialize arrays for each tidal component
tide_components = {constituent["symbol"]: np.zeros(total_hours) for constituent in constituents}
# Calculate amplitudes and phase shifts for each constituent
for constituent in constituents:
    amplitude = constituent["relative_amplitude"] / 100.0  # Normalize amplitude
    period = constituent["period"]
    phase_shift = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi)  # Random phase shift in radians
    tide_components[constituent["symbol"]] = amplitude*np.cos(2*np.pi / period * time - phase_shift)
# Sum all tidal components to create the final tide
total_tide = np.sum(list(tide_components.values()), axis=0)
# Plot the tidal chart
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(time, total_tide)
plt.title("Tidal Chart for a Month")
plt.xlabel("Time (hours)")
plt.ylabel("Water Level")
plt.grid(True)
# Display the plot
plt.show()
# Display the ratios for each location
ratios = {
    "Location 1": (tide_components["K1"] + tide_components["O1"]) / (tide_components["M2"] + tide_components["S2"]),
    "Location 2": (tide_components["K1"] + tide_components["O1"]) / (tide_components["M2"] + tide_components["S2"]),
    "Location 3": (tide_components["K1"] + tide_components["O1"]) / (tide_components["M2"] + tide_components["S2"]),
    "Location 4": (tide_components["K1"] + tide_components["O1"]) / (tide_components["M2"] + tide_components["S2"]),
}
# Display the ratios table
print("Ratios for Tide Plots:")
print("Location\t(K1+O1)/(M2+S2)")
for location, ratio in ratios.items():
    print(f"{location}\t\t{ratio:.4f}")
```

I'm trying to get a graph displaying the different tides and with the ratios.

I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it:

```
Ratios for Tide Plots:
Location    (K1+O1)/(M2+S2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0cd21def11d7> in <module>
     43 print("Location\t(K1+O1)/(M2+S2)")
     44 for location, ratio in ratios.items():
---> 45     print(f"{location}\t\t{ratio:.4f}")

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__

​
```

Comment: It looks like the values in your ratios dictionary are in fact numpy ndarrays. What are you expecting them to be?

Comment: Are you trying to print the entire ratio table formatted to 4 decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `ratio` is a NumPy array. You can format NumPy arrays for string printing with [`np.array2string`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html):

```
print(f"{location}\t\t{np.array2string(ratio, precision=4, floatmode='maxprec')}")
```

Once that is updated, your plot and output will print without error:

[image: plot]

```
Ratios for Tide Plots:
Location    (K1+O1)/(M2+S2)
Location 1
Location 1      [-2.7688e+00  2.5100e+00  1.0019e+00  7.1010e-01  #...]
```